# Min cost with dynamic programming in java

Tags: java, dynamic

I'm working on a project where I have to find the min cost with dynamic programming. We have an array `A[n*m]` filled. Also we have another array `b[n*m]`. We have to fill another `c(n*m)`array that `c(i,j)`filled with the minimum of

```
for (i=1 to m) 
  a[i,j]+B[j,k]+c[i-1,k]
```

for example we have [this arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sArL3.jpg).

This is my code:

```
for (int t = 1; t < n; t++) {
 for (int y = 0; y < m; y++) {
  int min = 9999555;
  for (int k = 0; k < m; k++) {
   if ((a[t][y] + b[y][k]) < min) {
    min= a[t][y] + b[y][k] + c[t - 1][k];
    }
   }c[t][y] += min;
  }
 }
 for (int u = 0; u < n; u++) {
        for (int z = 0; z < m; z++) {
            System.out.print(c[u][z]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

The first column of `c` should be the same with first of column of `a`. 
for example:
`c[2,1]` is`min{A[2,1]+c[1,1]+b[1,1], A[2,1]+C[1,2]+B[2,1],A[2,1]+c[1,3]+b[3,1]}`
I want to ask you if my code is correct method of dynamic programming.

Comment: the question itself has no relation to dynamic programming because you haven't defined the problem statement which (according to your words) is aimed to be solved by means of dyn.programming. We only see that you are trying to fill array C by means of arrays A and B

Comment: The plot of the problem is:We have N steps(processes) and M types of Virtual Machines VMs. The array A has the cost to run 1 process in a type of VM. The second array B M*M has the cost to run a process from a type of VM to another. In the example that I wrote, we have 4 processes and 3 types of VMs.First VM run the 4 processes with cost 5 7 7 and 2. Also communicate with the other types of VM with cost 7 and 2.

Comment: please define more clearly the meaning of A [i,j], B [i,j] and C [i,j]. A[i,j] = the cost of running process i on VM j. C[i,j] = the cost of running processes 0..i on VMs 0..j (correct?) B [i,j]=?

Comment: A[i,j] = the cost of running process i on VM j.C[i,j] = the cost of running processes 0..i on VMs 0..j  that caused from the sum of c[i-1,j] + the cost  of the process a[i,j] + the cost to run on the same virtual machine or the cost to send data to another VM (b[j,k]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's state things clearly:
A[i,j] is the cost of running process i on VM j

State C[i,j] implies the minimal cost of running processes "0..i" on VMs "0..j"

Let's assume for now, that there is no B cost array.

The goal is state C[n,m] which is the minimal cost of running processes "0..n" on VMs "0..m".
We may reach state C[i,j] from:

1. state C[i-1,j] which means that VMs "0..j" will run additional process "i" and taking into account the costs of running process "i" on VMs "0..j" that's sum(a[i,k]) where k=0..j
   Hence the cost is C[i-1, j] + sum(a[i,k]) where k=0..j
2. state C[i, j-1] which means that processes "0..j" will be running on one more VM "j" (so total "0..j") and taking into account the costs of running processes "0..i" on VM "j" that's sum(a[k,j]) where k=0..i
   Hence the cost is C[i, j-1] + sum(a[k,j]) where k=0..i

By taking minimum of these two values we find C[i,j]

Do you agree so far?

UPDATE.
Assuming that process and VM numbering starts from 0:

base case:

```
for(int j=0; j < m; j++)  
     c[ 0 ][ j ] = a[ 0 ][ j ];
```

DP loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) 
{
 for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) 
 {
     int min = Integer.MAX_INT;
     for (int k = 0; k < m; k++) 
      {
        if ((a[ i ][ j ] + b[ k ][ j ] + c[ i-1 ][ k ]) < min) 

             min= a[ i ][ j ] + b[ k ][ j ] + c[ i-1 ][ k ];

      }//try every VM

     c[ i ][ j ] = min;

  }//for every VM
}//for every process
```

Comment: @George now could you explain the purpose of B [i,j] a bit clearer? because i couldn't understand that point yet. I will add the needed conditions to my answer above

Comment: I tried to explain the solution in paper. [link](https://imgur.com/a/lk6HFWA)   Min(12,20,12) is 12 . Min(18,14,13) is 13 and Min(12,13,8) is 8.

Comment: @George, check the updated answer above. I didn't fully get what is the goal, but according to your draft in the link you provided (seems that it is different from what I was talking in the previous posts), the base case and the loop should look the way I posted

Comment: and according to the recursive step you provided, the first row (not column) should be the same for A and C.

Comment: the first row is i=0 (process 0) and it is the very first process so there is no VM change prior to it, so c[0][j]=a[0][j] for any VM

Comment: I think your opinion is correct, but my problem is that for large input with 50 processes and 20 VMs  I have wrong results.

Comment: The file with 50 processes is [] (https://expirebox.com/download/2442c0362478dbaa11441c604366eae9.html) , my results is https://expirebox.com/download/f6f3a8ffe9b65b5250d59f0e5185d13f.html and the correct results must be like this https://expirebox.com/download/df1404d55473e545d18f9fa50bc6eaef.html

Comment: @George could you share your project statement (some link or text file) ? Probably you derived an incorrect recursive relation

Comment: @George B[ i ][ j ] is the cost of transfering from VM i to VM j or from VM j to VM i ? Because you're using B [ j ][ k ] instead of B [ k ][ j ], probably you need to use B [ k ][ j ]

Comment: Thank you very much mangusta. That's my mistake. I use B[k][j] and it works fine .

Answer (score 0):

Visits to Cloud Work with Dynamic Programmers Companies are providing computing cloud computing like i Amazon, they are all about virtual man (VMs, virtual machines) which, in their turn, give them to the others Appropriate remuneration for the total use time. There are many sketches in the process with different each one, for example, one virtual machine A may be superior another virtual machine cost B to carry out the process use more of the CPU, while the B is superior to A in the processes that run the dsc. There may also be a more expensive C system that outperforms both A and B in the performance (but it is more expensive). The prediction of the design of the virtual machine is many financial resources. This problem is addressed to the specific work. We have an in-depth process consisting of N experiments in the form of chains: Δ1 → Δ2 → Δ3 → ..... → ΔΝ. The results show that the results of Δ1 pass as inputs to Δ2, those of Δ2 to Δ3, and so on. We also have M virtual pictorial facilities. As an entry, we also have 2 tables. The man is NXM and causes the total cost to run a transaction in one type of virtual machine. The dignitaries table is MXM and it pays the cost to send the data to another. An example input is the following: In the specific example, the embedded process has 4 scenarios and 3 VM patterns are available. The first performs the 4 routines with a cost of 5, 7, 7 and 2 respectively. It also communicates with the other two types of technicians with a cost of 7 and 2. Algorithm of Dynamic Programming to be implemented : an Algorithm to be filled table Costs NXM, where each Cost cell (i, j) shows the lowest overall cost of the process until i live when i live on the j j. In order to execute life on the move, it either goes the results of the i-1 be found to be either transferable to or from other communities taking into account the cost of communication. In the above example this table has the equivalence, which in practice means that less expensive extinction is 15 and is achieved when the last operation is a virtual machine: